# Return Indices of first elements in a nested list

Tags: c#, collections, generic-list

I have a List of a custom type which contains an Enumerated Type as a property.
I'd like to find the indices of all the first occurences of each enumeration in the enumerated type within my list.

I thought about outputing the distinct types and then finding firsts over this sequence but the First function requires a type for which i receive an error

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace space
{

    TypeEnum { E1, E2, E3}

    public class Class1
    {
        public TypeEnum Eobj { get; set; }
        public double doubObj { get; set; }

        public Class1()
        {
            doubObj = 0.0;
            Eobj = TypeEnum.E1;

        }

        public Class1(double doubObjIn, TypeEnum EobjIn)
        {
            doubObj =  doubObjIn;
            Eobj = EobjIn;

        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Class1> list1 = new List<Class1>();
        Class1 o1 = new Class1(1, TypeEnum.E1);
        Class1 o2 = new Class1(2, TypeEnum.E1);
        Class1 o3 = new Class1(3, TypeEnum.E2);

        list1.Add(o1);
        list1.Add(o2);
        list1.Add(o3);


        // first try to get a sequence of which enumerated types are present
        var ba = list1.Select(o => o.Eobj).Distinct();
        //then try to find where they are in the list
        var bb = list1.Select(o => o.Eobj).First(ba);



    }

}
```

Comment: are you getting some error with this code? or what is your expected result?

Comment: i get an error as the First function is generic and requires me to input a Type source

Comment: That second one doesn't make sense. What is `First` (when passed another list as an argument) supposed to do? Could you explain the desired behavior better?

Comment: Where is your "nested list"? You only have a single list in your code example. Note that the compiler error you're getting is the best that the compiler can come up with, but the issue isn't that you need to provide a type parameter, but rather that the `First()` method takes a delegate instance as a parameter, not a list. Did you mean something like `ba.First();` instead of `list1.Select(o => o.Eobj).First(ba);`? You need to be much clearer about what output you expect from this code.

Comment: I've updated the text to try to clarify

Comment: I don't want to use ba.First() because ba would (if i defined it correctly) just contain the Enum Types which exist as properties in the list. I want to check the location of them in the original list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I understood to be your ask.
Given a list with these items

```
List<Class1> list1 = new List<Class1>();
Class1 o1 = new Class1(1, TypeEnum.E1);
Class1 o2 = new Class1(2, TypeEnum.E1);
Class1 o3 = new Class1(3, TypeEnum.E2);
```

you want to reduce this to a list where only one object containing a `TypeEnum` is found. If this is the case, consider using [DistinctBy](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs)

And then, you can simply call it using

```
var newList = list1.DistinctBy(a => a.Eobj);
```

If you want to just get the indexes (indices?), then you can write it like this:

```
var indexes = list1.Select(x => x.Eobj).Distinct().Select(type => 
    list1.FindIndex(o => o.Eobj == type)).ToList();
```

If you want to find out the enum values, and their corresponding indexes in the list, you can write it like this:

```
var typesWithIndexes = list1.Select(x => x.Eobj).Distinct()
  .Select(type => new
    {
      Type = type,
      Index = list1.FindIndex(o => o.Eobj == type)
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm not trying to reduce the list, i'm rather trying to find which TypeEnum are present and what are the indices of the first occurences

Comment: ok thanks i think the last one is what i'm after...i'll test it now